# Appcenter Upgrade silently fails, GUI elements like dock icons disappear, applications menu doesn't open but causes wingpanel restart

Tags: updates, graphic-drivers, graphics, user-interface

since I couldn't spot any other reports I hope this only happened to me, but I had a pretty critical accident (at least for a GUI-only user it would have been) today. Though I mostly install and upgrade packages via `apt` from within the terminal, I sometimes check out Appcenters recommendations and when it wants to upgrade some packages, I happily grant it the favour ;-)

But this time, something broke. I first noticed that `gnome-minesweeper` had neither numbers and flags on the fields, nor were the title bar controls displayed properly. Later I noticed missing dock icons and sticky notification indicators on them (though the new mail had been read, in the case of Thunderbird), text missing from the lock screen (after putting into and waking from standby) and the Applications menu crashing wingpanel instantly (and/or causing it to restart). Apparently, the system ran fine, but the GUI seemed very damaged. In the meantime, Appcenter still showed pending system upgrades to apply while just having run.

I hope that really no one else has this problem, but just in case I want to at least show how I got back and have this as a place for discussion about how and why. It is quite likely that this was just caused by some modifications I made myself, though something like that still shouldn't happen, I guess.

Comment: Happens to me as well. Thanks a lot for your post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `apt` in the terminal revealed the problem: Probably connected to Spectre and Meltdown patches, some graphic driver upgrades seemed to cause dependency problems.

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[...]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (= 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 mesa-va-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  geany-common libdrm-common libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 libxslt1-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-101
  linux-headers-4.4.0-101-lowlatency linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-lowlatency linux-headers-4.4.0-104
  linux-headers-4.4.0-104-lowlatency linux-image-4.4.0-101-lowlatency linux-image-4.4.0-103-lowlatency
  linux-image-4.4.0-104-lowlatency mod-host mod-ui mod-ui-common phantomjs python-lockfile python3-pystache python3-serial
  python3-tornado
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/60,3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20,5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 656858 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) over (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1~16.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x) over (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1~16.04.1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After googling a bit on how to reverse such an unsuccessful ugrade, I came across [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/ubuntu-linux-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade/) which gave me enough info to adopt for my problem. `$ grep -A 3 'Start-Date: 2018-01-17' /var/log/apt/history.log` revealed one big chunk of text:

```
[...]
--
Start-Date: 2018-01-17  10:05:28
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Requested-By: peter (1000)
Upgrade: libgles2-mesa:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), uget-chrome-wrapper:amd64 (2.0.6-1, 2.0.7-1), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libglapi-mesa:i386 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), mesa-common-dev:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), carla-git:amd64 (2:1.9.7+git20180106, 2:1.9.8+git20180116), libgbm1:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), carla-lv2:amd64 (2:1.9.7+git20180106, 2:1.9.8+git20180116), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libllvm5.0:amd64 (1:5.0-3~16.04.1, 1:5.0.1-1~oibaf~x), libllvm5.0:i386 (1:5.0-3~16.04.1, 1:5.0.1-1~oibaf~x), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2:2.99.917+git1706071933.6babcf~gd~x, 2:2.99.917+git1801120736.26f540~oibaf~x), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), carla-data:amd64 (2:1.9.7+git20180106, 2:1.9.8+git20180116), libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.28ubuntu0.6, 0.28ubuntu0.7), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), carla-vst:amd64 (2:1.9.7+git20180106, 2:1.9.8+git20180116), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libosmesa6:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libosmesa6:i386 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libgbm-dev:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x), libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.89+git1801151830.57d3d4~oibaf~x), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2, 17.4~git1801160730.1cbcd7~oibaf~x)
--
[...]
```

I didn't have previous knowledge of this, but it didn't take long to guess (and hope) that the brackets contained `(original-version, upgrade-target-version)`. Then I just copied this into a text editor and batch edited this to fit the format `package-name:arch=original-version package-[...]`, so I could easily copy-paste that back into the terminal to use with `sudo apt install` to downgrade to the versions that at least worked. But `apt` wasn't too happy with this and complained a bit, so with the goal of just getting something through I simply removed the packages from that list again of which it couldn't find the original versions somehow.

```
[...]
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.0.6-1' for 'uget-chrome-wrapper' was not found
E: Version '2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3' for 'gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0' was not found
E: Version '2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3' for 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0' was not found
E: Version '2:1.9.7+git20180106' for 'carla-git' was not found
E: Version '2:1.9.7+git20180106' for 'carla-lv2' was not found
E: Version '2:2.99.917+git1706071933.6babcf~gd~x' for 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' was not found
E: Version '2:1.9.7+git20180106' for 'carla-data' was not found
E: Version '0.28ubuntu0.6' for 'distro-info-data' was not found
E: Version '2:1.9.7+git20180106' for 'carla-vst' was not found
E: Version '2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3' for 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common' was not found
E: Version '2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3' for 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev' was not found
$ sudo apt install libgles2-mesa:[...]
[...]
E: Version '2:2.99.917+git1706071933.6babcf~gd~x' for 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' was not found
E: Version '0.28ubuntu0.6' for 'distro-info-data' was not found
```

...but finally, it let me through.

```
Reading state information... Done
libdrm-amdgpu1 is already the newest version (2.4.83-1~16.04.1).
libdrm-amdgpu1 set to manually installed.
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 is already the newest version (2.4.83-1~16.04.1).
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  geany-common libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0 libxslt1-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-101
  linux-headers-4.4.0-101-lowlatency linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-lowlatency linux-headers-4.4.0-104
  linux-headers-4.4.0-104-lowlatency linux-image-4.4.0-101-lowlatency linux-image-4.4.0-103-lowlatency
  linux-image-4.4.0-104-lowlatency mod-host mod-ui mod-ui-common phantomjs python-lockfile python3-pystache python3-serial
  python3-tornado
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Recommended packages:
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc | libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 | libtxc-dxtn0
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2
  libdrm2:i386 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libgbm-dev libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev libllvm5.0
  libllvm5.0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa mesa-common-dev mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 30 downgraded, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 47,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 59,2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 [1.718 kB]
[...]
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git1801120736.26f540~oibaf~x) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
$
```

And indeed, it worked! The GUI is back to normal, at least for now. I will be careful with upgrading for a while, but I wanted to at least share this.